# Post on friend's wall from october 2013 onwards

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing an iOS and android app in which I have to give a functionality to user so as he can post on my App's wall from their account. I have found in Facebook developers forum that this functionality has been removed. 
Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve the same anyhow. 
Please provide a link if possible.

Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Apps don't have a 'wall' since February of 2013 or so - your app can have a Page, but there's nothing special about that page or how users can write posts on the page's timeline via the API - it's just the [normal documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed#pubfields) for posting to `/<page>/feed` on behalf of your app's users

Comment: @lgy: Thanks for the response.


Post will be posted on app's fb page or on user's page? 

See my requirement is as "I am a user. I am using an app say demo app on my iPhone. Now I want to post any suggestion/score/anything on demo app's fb page not on my page/wall". I hope requirement must be more clear now

Comment: If you get the appropriate permissions from a user (publish_actions) you can post things to pages on their behalf, including the page of your app - it'll appear in the 'posts by others' section of the page